# How to access virtual machine's files from OSX?

Tags: ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, virtual-machine, parallels

I'm running an Ubuntu 10.10 VM under Parallels Desktop in Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

I need to make the filesystem of this VM available to OS X.  I can do it the other way around, where my OS X folders show up inside the VM, but this isn't acceptable, unfortunately.

I've installed Parallels Tools, but this doesn't make any new options available to me in the VM configuration.

I fully realize that this might be the easiest thing in the world, but for whatever reason, I'm not finding a simple answer.

Comment: oh, one question - what do you want, sharing files when your VM is online, or only do it when the VM is stopped?

Comment: I need to share files when it's online, if that's possible.

Comment: it is. use NFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do it with a live system is to export it via NFS on the Linux VM and then use "Go to foder" in finder (Shift-Cmd-G) on the Mac host and enter

`/net/vmhost`

or whatever hostname your VM has. If the name does not wirk, try the IP address.

Comment: I'm giving this a try now. Never used NFS before though, so we'll see how it goes!

Comment: if you are in a network where you trust everyone and you "just want to read + write" try this as export line in /etc/exports: /myexport *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

Comment: Exporting an nfs share actually ended up being a huge headache, unfortunately.  I ended up using MacFusion to mount the VM as an SSHFS share, and it was a lot easier than setting up and configuring nfs.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: why? That should not be so hard :-) can you elaborate on the (Linux?) problems?

Comment: I'm trying it with NFSv4, but even with the same usernames and idmapping enabled, it still won't give access. Always permission denied for some reason. Perhaps even the domains need to match?